# Neural Networks Python

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, neural-network

I am trying to build a simple neural network which takes 8 inputs and 2 outputs, from an xls file which has 500 rows of data, with 2 hidden weights in a matrix (8, 2). Currently, the neuron has not started to learn anything. Its jus a sample code to make it run for random weights. Here is my code

```
def sigmoid(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return sigmoid(x,False)*(1-sigmoid(x,False))
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def neuron(inputs, weights):                
    weighted_input = np.dot(inputs, weights)
    return sigmoid(weighted_input, False)

weights = 2 * np.random.random((8,2)) - 1
W = np.array([weights])

error1 = []
for i in range(500):
    for k in range (2):
        X = X_T[i] #list of 8 Inputs from xls 
        T = T_T[i] #list of 2 outputs from xls
        Y = neuron(X, W)[k]
        error1.append(np.sqrt((Y[k] - T) ** 2))    

print W
print np.average(error1)
pl.plot(error1)
```

I want this code to run for the two hidden weights which are random at the moment. that is why i have set the range of k as 2. But when i try to run this, i get the following error.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-b300ce507da8> in <module>()
     20         X = X_T[i]
     21         T = T_T[i]
---> 22         Y = neuron(X, W)[k]
     23         error1.append(np.sqrt((Y[k] - T) ** 2))
     24 

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I get that i have messed up the loop. but i do not know how to work this out.

Comment: Your function returns a float, and you're trying to access such value via an index. This clearly raise an error.

Comment: could u please help me rectify it? i m kinda new to python

Comment: Y = neuron(X, W)[k] I think this should be  Y = neuron(X, k)? Why are you sending in the output as weights?

Comment: You probably want to have `k` instead of `i` in the `T_T` list, and simply remove the `[k]` after `neuron(X, W)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in loops is rather inefficient. This code benefits from optimized matrix manipulations and should be doing approximately what you want if I understood it correctly.

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        s = sigmoid(x,False)
        return s*(1-s)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

n_in = 8
n_out = 2
n_data = 500

X = np.random.randn( n_data, n_in )
T = np.random.randn( n_data, n_out )

W = np.random.randn( n_out, n_in )
b = np.random.randn( n_out, )

err = ( sigmoid( np.dot(X, W.T) + b ) - T ) ** 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In  `Y = neuron(X, W)[k]`:

**neuron(X, W)** is return a float value. So you get error.

If `neuron(X, W)` is return a `list/tuple...so on`, you can get value by index.

Example:

```
>>> L = [1,2][0]
>>> L
1
>>>
```